# Move folders recursively in their own group

Tags: powershell

I have 2 folders like this

```
Alfa X - Volume 1
Alfa X - Volume 2
```

This script

```
$Folder    = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Some\Path -Filter "*volume*" -Directory -Recurse #| ForEach-Object -Process { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination C:\Some\OtherFolder }
$Folder1   = $Folder.FullName.split('\')[-1]
$newFolder =  "$($Folder1.Split(' ')[0])" + " $($Folder1.Split(' ')[1])"
If(-not (Test-Path -Path C:\Some\Path\$newFolder)){
    New-Item -Path C:\some\path -Name $newFolder -ItemType Directory -OutVariable Location
    }

    
Foreach($Directory in $Folder.FullName){
    Move-Item -Path $Directory -Destination $Location.FullName}
```

create (if not exists) and move these folders into a folder called

```
Alfa X -
```

What is the problem?
it doesn't work recursively. I try to explain. If I have a set of folders like this

```
Alfa X - Volume 1
Alfa X - Volume 2
beta - volume 4
beta - volume 6
```

This script moves all folders in Alfa X in this way

```
Alfa X -
|
|
|----- Alfa X - Volume 1
|----- Alfa X - Volume 2
|----- beta - volume 4
|----- beta - volume 6
```

But I don't want this. I wish that it moves folders in this way

```
Alfa X
|
|---- Alfa X - Volume 1
|---- Alfa X - Volume 2
|
beta
|
|---- beta - volume 4
|---- beta - volume 6
```

**Question**: is it possible to move folders recursively in their own group? By 'own group' I mean folders that have the same name until they find the word 'volume' or a keyword in their name that differentiate them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend to use separated source and target directories but if I got it right something like this should work actually:

```
$SourcePath = 'C:\Some\Path'
$TargetPath = 'C:\someOther\path'

$FolderList = Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -Filter "*volume*" -Directory 

foreach ($Folder in $FolderList) {
    $Name1 = ($Folder.Name -split '-')[0].Trim()
    $TargetFolder = Join-Path -Path $TargetPath -ChildPath $Name1
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $TargetFolder)) {
        New-Item -Path $TargetFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    Move-Item -Path $Folder.FullName -Destination $TargetFolder
}
```